# How to pass values greater than std::numeric_limits<fundamental_type>::max() to a function?

Tags: c++, types, error-handling, type-conversion, numeric-limits

I am writing a function `void func(K const& val)`, which part of a template class.

Assume I define a class object as `foo<unsigned short int> f;` and then I call func as `f.func(999999);`

What happens is the value `999999`gets converted to some other value as it itself is out of range. How do I prevent this from happening? Is there a compiler flag or some other way in code where I can prevent this?

Checking

```
if(val > std::numeric_limits<K>::max())
```

inside the `func` does not help, as the value is already converted when it is getting passed and into something that is inside the numeric limit.

For example, 999998989898988989999 gets converted to 11823

How do I pass values greater than std::numeric_limits::max() to a function?

P.S. I am compiling using gcc (with -std=c++11)

Comment: gcc should issue a warning in this case. Set `-Werror` and you'll get a compilation error when trying to do such things.

Comment: @Rostislav: And if the code does not say `f.func(999999);` but `f.func(x + y);`?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the definition of your class `foo` is something like:

```
template<typename K>
class foo {
public:
    void func(K const& k) {}
};
```

You could make `func` template itself, and check for limits before calling the actual implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename K>
class foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value && !std::is_signed<K>::value> func(T const& t) 
    {
        if (t < 0 || static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(t) > std::numeric_limits<K>::max()) {
            std::cout << "error\n";
            return;
        }
        
        func_impl(t);
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_signed<T>::value && std::is_signed<K>::value> func(T const& t) 
    {
        if (t > static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<K>>(std::numeric_limits<K>::max())) {
            std::cout << "error\n";
            return;
        }
        
        func_impl(t);
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value == std::is_signed<K>::value> func(T const& k)
    {
        if (k < std::numeric_limits<K>::min() || k > std::numeric_limits<K>::max()) {
            std::cout << "error\n";
            return;
        }
        func_impl(k);
    }
    
private:
    void func_impl(K const& k) 
    {
        std::cout << "normal\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    foo<char>().func(127);
    foo<char>().func(127u);
    foo<char>().func(-128);
    foo<char>().func(128);
    foo<char>().func(128u);
    foo<char>().func(-129);
    foo<unsigned>().func(-1);
    foo<int>().func(1u);
}
```

Output:

> normal
>
> normal
>
> normal
>
> error
>
> error
>
> error
>
> error
>
> normal

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/NJC86128)

**Edit**

As @BaumMitAugen pointed out, [boost::numeric_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html) would probably be a better alternative to manual `if`s in my implementation of `func` - it will throw an exception if an underflow or overflow occurs and you will avoid a lot of boilerplate of the latest edited version of code which (a) works and (b) avoids signed/unsigned comparison warnings.

Comment: Does not work for "underflows". http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f7f95ec70c5eb7 Let's see if I can break the overflow too. ;) But probably not, looks fine.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yeah, didn't test it too much. The signed/unsigned conversions should definitely be accounted for and tested extensively. The signed underflow should be fine though :)

Comment: Ha, got a false positive! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25e23233d8bb3b3e This is fun. :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is fun indeed.

Comment: Looks like that should work. Maybe throw in a `static_cast` to get rid of sign-conversion warnings. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9d7eaf6ca460453 Last remark: boost.numeric_cast already implements this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well, that was a bit more boilerplate than I'd like to see. `boost::numeric_cast` is a way better approach (live and learn...). Plus, the latest version of code still has a lot of room to grow - limiting the code to integral types only or treating floating point ones correctly, etc. But I guess it's out of the scope for this question. Thanks for helping me improve the answer :)